# Getting error to create data fusion build pipeline through cli method

Tags: google-cloud-platform, pipeline, google-cloud-data-fusion

Getting error to create data fusion pipeline through cli method. Need help on this.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MELR5.png)

We are trying to create data fusion pipeline through CLI sdk but I am getting the error (already shared).
We want to be use cli for data fusion setup instead of GCP console.

Comment: Did you check this doc first: https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/beta/datapipelines/pipeline/create

Comment: The gcloud command that you're using is for Data Flow, not Data Fusion. Data Fusion doesn't have a gcloud sdk command for deploying and running pipelines. You will need to use the HTTP API for that: https://cloud.google.com/data-fusion/docs/reference/cdap-reference